# How to give\restrict check in and check out permissions for specific user in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

Is there any ways to give permission to one particular user for check in and check out without creating groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can select `Add Windows user or group` directly to the current permission level: In the Project Security dialog box, Choose “Windows User or Group” in the “Add users and groups” section. Then click “Add” to add the Windows user/group.

[image]